# I have a png file with no background, how can I create a clear color background for this image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, core-image

So I understand that a UIImage inherently doesn't have a background. As many of us know, a lot of PNG files don't have a background Color thus making it clear. I'm attempting to upload a png file that doesn't have a background color, thus a clear color. Yes, I know I can set the background Color myself in adobe or sketch, but I'm assuming that other users don't know how to do this.

Here is a screenshot of the png that I have created:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, it's just two lines that are unioned together so there's no background set.

Now below is a screenshot of the aftermath of using the imagePicker to choose this png image from my photo roll.

[image: screenshot]

Notice that the area that is supposed to be transparent is actually black. I want to color in the black part and make it actually clearColor instead and keep the green cross as it is. Now, I'm not sure if the black color is actually even a black color because perhaps it's just empty space. Can I fill in the empty black space and turn it into a clear color?

Here's my code right now that isn't working very well:

```
func overlayImage(image: UIImage, color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: rect)
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = color
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)

    let gcSize: CGSize = backgroundView.frame.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gcSize)

    let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    backgroundView.layer.renderInContext(context)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Any help in either obj-C or Swift would be greatly appreciated.

I got rid of the overlay method above and am using the code below:

**Updated with new code that still doesn't work**

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    scaleImage(overlayImage(image, color: UIColor.clearColor()))
}

func scaleImageAndAddAugmented(image: UIImage?) {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image!.size.width, image!.size.height)
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: rect)
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(image!.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.25, 0.25))
    let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
    image!.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(image!.size.width), Int(image!.size.height), 8, 0,  CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

    let myGeneratedImage  = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, myGeneratedImage)

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    // set image below
}
```

Comment: why don't you create a custom cross png image and add it ?

Comment: Is the black part actually clear in the PNG? Or is it currently black and you want it to be clear?

Comment: Clarify how this is being used and what values relate to the image you posted in the question.

Comment: updated. It's supposed to be clear and is currently black and I want it to be clear.

Comment: Try changing `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gcSize);` to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(gcSize, NO, 0);`.

Comment: My code is actually blocking out the entire image instead and the background is still black with changing it to WithOptions

Comment: The cross actually appears to have some alpha transparency.

Comment: Right you are @MitchellCurrie. I have it set on the viewDidLoad to have an alpha of 0.3, but that isn't the issue currently. I'm attempting to make it show the correct background color of a png file that is actually clear color.

Comment: I think I know this. Let me dig some code for an answer

Comment: Thanks @MitchellCurrie!

Comment: Are you 100% sure your PNG has the alpha channel?

Comment: the png has no background it looks like this typically: http://i.imgur.com/XA2h0Z0.png and you can see that there is no background on it by comparing it with this one: http://imgur.com/XA2h0Z0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit of excess work to use UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext to generate an image from context, when you can just create an image from a file.

As first mentioned it is required to have Opaque = NO:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
```

My bet is its the image itself, because the whole thing is faded.

Make 100% certain that the passed colour is a clear colour for:

```
backgroundView.backgroundColor = color
```

You could create a bitmap context and use that instead:

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                     width,
                                     height,
                                     8,
                                     0,
                                     rgbColorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

Rather than using the current context and you can use:

```
myGeneratedImage  = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
```

Drawing is easy as pie:

```
CGContextDrawImage(realContext,bounds,myGeneratedImage)
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. I wish I can attempt this now but away from computer. I'll let you know soon how it goes.

Comment: i'm not sure this is working as intended, i have updated my question with more code if you have time to take another look.

Comment: Can you change CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipledLast to  CGImageAlphaInfo.Last

Comment: Ah Mitchell! I figured it out. I made one little mistake.

Comment: my bool was set to true because I had already set it to false initially, but setting the opaque to no solved it!

Comment: Thanks. Does the solution need to be amended?

Comment: Nope, I can post my code below for Swift purposes but your code is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Swift code below:

```
func scaleImage(image: UIImage?) {
    if let image = image {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)

        let size: CGSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(image.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.25, 0.25))

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(image.size.width), Int(image.size.height), 8, 0,  CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

        let myGeneratedImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)

        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, myGeneratedImage)

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```